# Get substring using regex in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, substring

**Context**

I've been going back & forth for a couple of hours trying to solve something and am still not satisfied with the result.

I want to get the username of an iPhone from UIDevice both in English and Spanish. So I've come up with a regex to get ("Andres's iPhone" > "Andres") and ("iPhone de Andres" > "Andres").

The magic is something like:

`"(?:iPhone|iphone|phone|iPad|ipad|pad|iPod|ipod|pod)(?:\\s+\\S+)*\\s+de\\s+(.+)|"`
`"(.+)'s\\s+(?:iPhone|iphone|phone|iPad|ipad|pad|iPod|ipod|pod)(?:\\s+\\S+)*"`

**Problem**

When trying to get the substring from `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]` the user name can be matched by one of the two alternatives in the regex.

This causes that the actual name might be obtained by:

`[[regEx firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])] rangeAtIndex:1]`

if the first alternative matched; but if the second alternative performs the match, then it is:

`[[regEx firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])] rangeAtIndex:2]`

Notice that, according to the alternative matching, I have to get the first index or the second. For the moment I've worked around this with:

```
+ (NSString *)getSubstringInString:(NSString *)str matchedByRegEx:(NSRegularExpression *)regEx
{
  NSString * result = nil;

  NSTextCheckingResult * match = [regEx firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
  for (int i=1; i<[match numberOfRanges]; i++) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
    if (!NSEqualRanges(matchRange, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
      result = [str substringWithRange:matchRange];
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

**Actual question**

But is there a better way to get the matching substring, disregarding what was the alternative from the regex used ?

Hope I've made myself clear, thanks in advance for any possible help!

Answer (score 1):

I will get to your question shortly but first some enhancements by using:

```
options: .CaseInsensitive
```

with `NSRegularExpression` you avoid using expression with and without casing.

So this

```
(?:iPhone|iphone|phone|iPad|ipad|pad|iPod|ipod|pod)
```

becomes

```
(?:iphone|phone|ipad|pad|ipod|pod)
```

Next by enhancement is `i` as optional you could still match the other options like:

```
[i]*(phone|pad|pod)
```

The expression you need may look like this now:

```
(?>[i]*(?:phone|pad|pod)\s*de\s)(.+)|(.+)(?='s\s[i]*phone|pad|pod)
```

The final touch is:

```
let sample:String = "Andres's iPhone"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?>[i]*(?:phone|pad|pod)\\s*de\\s)(.+)|(.+)(?='s\\s[i]*phone|pad|pod)"
 , options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)

let match = regex.firstMatchInString(sample, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: sample.characters.count))

print((sample as NSString).substringWithRange(match!.range))
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvements. I totally overlooked the caps thing: I do set the caseinsensitive option but forgot to update the expression. Good catch!

Comment: Regarding the question though, if I do match!.range ([match range] in objc) I get the full range of the string, not the matching expression.